# Dealing with dynamic dataset configurations for 3NF data for generic UI screens

Tags: database-design

I'm working with a client who has a desktop windows application suite whose database contains GIS associated data (ie. survey results, programs, inspections etc.) specific to each of their customers. The data is in 3NF and any further normalization of the data is a non starter for the client. The client's application suite is designed so that they have a single install for all of their customers and any customization is to be done through meta data and configuration tables associated to each customer. Each customer has their own terminology for the problem domain, entities, fields etc.; furthermore each customers data sets are different with regards to what is being handed over to the UI. At the end of the day the UI is handed two arguments, one dictionary (column name, column display), and one dataset (standard column and row structure with the column name in the data set matching a column name entry in the dictionary argument).

Now the client's current implemented solution to the problem is to have a "customer-resultset" table (for the ViewModel/Control to find the dataset associated to a customer for a specific UI View), a "column-display" table (which specifies a datatable, columnname, column-displayname) and finally a "Xref" table to maintain the many to many relationship between "customer-resultset" and "column-display" along with join conditions for the tables involved in the defined result set. The key limitation of this implementation is that the system is slow as the actual query for the result set is not defined anywhere; so the query for the data is dynamically compiled at the individual execution time of the result by looking against all the tables involved in the result set, looking at database defined foreign keys/constraints along with the join conditions within the "Xref" table.

Considering the query does not change unless the result set definition is changed; avoiding the overhead of discovering the query prior to execution of the query seems to me a natural starting point for addressing performance ie. save the query somewhere. What would be my options? I've considered either generating/altering a database view each time a "customer-resultset" is defined, or storing the actual query within a column somewhere. Pros/cons to these approaches? Is it acceptable to have SQL query's syntax stored within a SQL database column? Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have already answered the question yourself. Depending on your database and client side code platform, one of these may apply as the best solution in terms of performance, maintainability and servicability. It is a typical metadata question. Consider for instance the data dictionary of a relational database; with each column it stores metadata.

In this case you do not want to write your own database engine (which might be yet another option if you have sufficient resources :-) but emulate this relation database on a virtual machine that happens to be a relation database with some procedural possibilities (at least at client side and maybe server side).

We maintain a similar package ourselves and have a repository that stores the definitions. Depending on the type of application and needs, we can choose between:

- Generate code at compile time (DDL and views) and yes this includes SQL query syntax stored with the column definition (view itgen_view_columns_v in our case). This can be quite complex to extremely complex code since it contains many optimizations for the target platform in our case.
- Generate code at runtime and let it stay valid for some time. This is generally not so good because dynamic generation of code in a database environment requires the database server to work hard on parsing and maybe maintaining the data dictionary of itself (DDL).
- Completely runtime evaluate the repository and adapt automatically. This is typically done client side since most procedural extensions to database engine do not perform very well nor do they come with OO, as many libraries and tools as C# or Java, although the procedural extensions are very handy for data intensive operations.
- Handcode in some specific situations the data model extensions (for instance in our case you can add your own fields with specific properties to for instance product in logistics).

In your case I would be probably be generating database views when just running on one database platform (queries get quicker) or interpreting client side everything in all other situations.

Comment: @JoanieBrar: was this post helpful to you? If so, please accept, else clarify.